# Applying operations on groups without aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to apply an operation on multiple groups of a data frame and then fill all values of that group by the result. Lets take mean and np.cumsum as an example and the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,3,2,4],"b":[1,1,2,2]})
```

which looks like this

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  3  1
2  2  2
3  4  2
```

Now I want to group the dataframe by `b`, then take the mean of `a` in each group, then apply `np.cumsum` to the means, and then replace all values of `a` by the (group dependent) result.

For the first three steps, I would start like this

```
df.groupby("b").mean().apply(np.cumsum)
```

which gives

```
   a
b   
1  2
2  5
```

But what I want to get is

```
   a  b
0  2  1
1  2  1
2  5  2
3  5  2
```

Any ideas how this can be solved in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df1 = df.groupby("b").mean().cumsum()
print (df1)
   a
b   
1  2
2  5

df['a'] = df['b'].map(df1['a'])
print (df)
   a  b
0  2  1
1  2  1
2  5  2
3  5  2
```